# PHP SoapClient converting HTML characters

Tags: php, xml, soap

I know this has been asked in a variety of different ways, but I cannot seem to find one that fits my situation.
I'm sending XML data via SOAP in this format:

```
<PRODUCTS>
<PRODUCT>
<REFERENCE>p_3304</REFERENCE>
<PRICE>560</PRICE>
```

But if I echo out the ->__getLastRequest() I get this:

```
&lt;PRODUCTS&gt;
&lt;PRODUCT&gt;
&lt;REFERENCE&gt;p_3304&lt;/REFERENCE&gt;
&lt;PRICE&gt;560&lt;/PRICE&gt;
```

As far as I can tell, nothing has changed my end in how the request is built and formatted, yet suddenly it is doing this.
I've tried adding and removing CDATA from certain tags, tried with and without htmlentities() and html_entity_decode(), but it always appears to do this.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's correct and necessary behaviour. If the characters were not encoded, their syntactic meaning would take place and it would make the SOAP request invalid. The receiving end will get the data decoded, so there's no need to do it anyway.

Comment: Sadly the receiving end are saying that because of this, they are unable to process the data we sent.  Is this more likely a case of them being wrong then?

Comment: It's difficult to say, for example your xml might be invalid, your sample is missing closing `</PRODUCT></PRODUCTS>`, but maybe it's just a sample.